# py2neo v2020.1 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo.ext'

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am following the Nicole White Neo4j Blog tutorial using the [py2neo V3](https://py2neo.org/v3/), but I am using the V.2020.1.1 instead.

I would like to use the function `GregorianCalendar`, but as my code runs

```
from py2neo.ext.calendar import GregorianCalendar 
# the way to import GregorianCalendar in py2neo V3
```

I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo.ext'

So I have been looking for `GregorianCalendar` in [py2neo V.2020.1.1 documentation](https://py2neo.org/2020.1/search.html?q=gregorian), but I can't find it. 
Does the function exist in this version?

If not, is there a similar one? Is it possible to get the same results with some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the py2neo.ext.calendar module no longer exist in py2neo V. 2020.1,
I implemented myself a custom `gregorian_calendar` function.

```
gregorian_calendar(graph, time1=some_time, node1=some_node)
```

Given the desired date and graph as input, it is useful to create a chain of

```
(:Calendar { calendar_type: 'Gregorian' })-[:YEAR]->
(:Year { year: 'that year', key: 'that year' })-[:MONTH]->
(:Month { month: 'that month (in number)', key: 'that month-year' })-[:DAY]->
(:Day { day: 'that day (in number)', key: 'that day-month-year' })
```

If time is not passed as parameter, the function uses the time resulting from `datetime.now()` to determine this year, month and day.

if `some_node` is also passed as input, the function also creates (`merge`s) the branch

```
(:Day { day: 'that day (in number)', key: 'that day-month-year' })-[:ON]->(:some_node)
```

---

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
from datetime import datetime


# equivalente del gregorian calendar
def gregorian_calendar(graph, time1=None, node1=None):

    if time1 is None:
        time1 = datetime.now()

    # gregorian calendar node
    gregorian_node = Node("Calendar", calendar_type="Gregorian")
    gregorian_node.__primarylabel__ = list(gregorian_node.labels)[0]
    gregorian_node.__primarykey__ = "calendar_type"
    graph.merge(gregorian_node)

    # year node
    that_year_node = Node("Year", year=time1.year, key=time1.strftime("%Y"))
    that_year_node.__primarylabel__ = list(that_year_node.labels)[0]
    that_year_node.__primarykey__ = "year"
    graph.merge(that_year_node)

    # calendar has year
    rel = Relationship(gregorian_node, "YEAR", that_year_node)
    graph.merge(rel)

    # month node
    that_month_node = Node("Month", month=time1.month, key=time1.strftime("%m-%Y"))
    that_month_node.__primarylabel__ = list(that_month_node.labels)[0]
    that_month_node.__primarykey__ = "month"
    graph.merge(that_month_node)

    # year has month
    rel = Relationship(that_year_node, "MONTH", that_month_node)
    graph.merge(rel)

    # day node
    that_day_node = Node("Day", day=time1.day, key=time1.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    that_day_node.__primarylabel__ = list(that_day_node.labels)[0]
    that_day_node.__primarykey__ = "day"
    graph.merge(that_day_node)

    # month has day
    rel = Relationship(that_month_node, "DAY", that_day_node)
    graph.merge(rel)

    # post was published on (gregorian) day
    if node1 is not None:
        rel = Relationship(node1, "ON", that_day_node)
        graph.create(rel)
```

Answer (score 1):

This module no longer exists, and hasn't done for some time. There's no equivalent time tree functionality in recent versions, although Neo4j now supports native date/time type, which it didn't back then.